# Snowflake SCIM access token notfication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, integration

I'm integrating Snowflake with Azure AD but the Snowflake token expires in 6 months. I want to create a notification. I'm thinking to create other table that will saving the data of execution of query - so near 6 month I will send the notification. Can you help me with that?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/snowflake-provisioning-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You may run the following command to get the start time of the token generation:

```
select START_TIME, QUERY_TEXT from account_usage.query_history where QUERY_TEXT like '%select system$generate_scim_access_token%' order by start_time desc;
```

Then store this in new table column and use it for notification purposes.

For eg:

```
 /* new table for storing the token start time*/                          
        create or replace table scimtoken(start_date timestamp);
    
 /* storing the value of latest token run*/
    insert into scimtoken (start_date)
                                  select max(START_TIME) from snowflake.account_usage.query_history where QUERY_TEXT like '%select system$generate_scim_access_token%' order by start_time desc;
                                  
 /* selecting the value from new table*/                              
    select * from scimtoken;
```

Based on this you may then build a notification mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Srinath, will try out the solutions, looks like it will solve my purposed.